# Controlling WPF Animations in Xaml

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

I have 2 animations defined to flash cell values in my grid, one when the value increases and one when the value decreases.

When running the application in debug I see a huge amount of warnings in the output window along the lines of:-

> Unable to perform action because the specified Storyboard was never applied to this object for interactive control.; Action='Stop'; Storyboard='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';

My animation is fired via a data trigger as follows:-

[image]

The Storyboards are as follows:

[image]

Given that it seems like the StopStoryboard is the problem, i.e. there is no storyboard running that needs stopping. Also my understanding is that starting a new animation in WPF will replace any existing animations already running. However if I remove the StopStoryboard from both DataTriggers I get another problem. This time only the BidDownStory will fire. I will never see the cells Animate Blue.

Another interesting thing is happening sometimes. If the animation is happening off screen (i.e. the column is not visible) and I scroll so that the column is visible I see the animation as expected. However if I then scroll the grid back to the column is off screen again the animation continues to run but against a different column in the grid!

If you can provide any help with fixing these issues It would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try something like this instead:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=RowData.Row.BidUp}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource AnimateCellBlue}" />
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource AnimateCellRed}" />
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thanks CodeNaked. That fixes the warning. So simple I can't believe I didn't think of it myself. Now I just need to work out why scrolling causes the wrong cells to animate.